# ActiveRecord inner join using name from has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have these two basic ActiveRecord models (Rails 4.2):

```
class ImportJob < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :logs, class_name: 'ImportLog', foreign_key: 'job_id', dependent: :destroy
end

class ImportLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job, class_name: 'ImportJob', foreign_key: :job_id
end
```

I'm trying to run a query on `ImportJob` with an `INNER JOIN` on `ImportLog`, using the name I gave it in the `has_many` declaration:

```
ImportJob.joins(:logs).where(logs: { stage: "load", status: "succeeded" })
```

However, ActiveRecord does not automatically use the name `logs` when constructing the `INNER JOIN`. This is the error with the SQL it generated:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "logs"
LINE 1: ..."import_logs"."job_id" = "import_jobs"."id" WHERE "logs"."st...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "import_jobs".* FROM "import_jobs" INNER JOIN "import_logs" ON "import_logs"."job_id" = "import_jobs"."id" WHERE "logs"."stage" = $1 AND "logs"."status" = $2
```

---

These two queries both work, but they seem either unintuitive or inelegant:

1. Refer to "logs" using the table name "import_logs" (unintuitive).

   ```
   ImportJob.joins(:logs).where(import_logs: { stage: "load", status: "succeeded" })
   ```
2. Write the `INNER JOIN` myself and include "AS logs" (inelegant).

   ```
   ImportJob.joins("INNER JOIN import_logs AS logs ON logs.job_id = import_jobs.id")
        .where(logs: { stage: "load", status: "succeeded" })
   ```

Is there a better solution than these?

Comment: Nope, welcome to ActiveRecord. The `join` expects the relation name from the model, whereas the `where` expects the table name (likely because its faster to execute that way).

Answer (score 0):

The more arguments you have to provide to `belongs_to` and other relation declarations, the more pain you are setting yourself up for in the future. As clunky as `import_job.import_logs` sounds, your AR models should be as simple as possible even at the cost of a certain degree of elegance.

Instead, build your beautiful, elegant API as a layer between your AR models and your controllers. Limit it to just the operations you need, not the unlimited operations that `ActiveRecord::Base` permits. Take that opportunity to define a clean, just-enough interface to your import system, with the AR models as an implementation detail. It will pay dividends in the future.